# How do I make 'beep' work over HDMI

Tags: setup

After adding `hdmi_drive=2` in the `/boot/config.txt` and rebooting I can get audio playback when typing `sudo aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav`.  After `sudo install beep` I can not get the `beep` to play over HDMI. I have added `sudo amixer cset numid=3 2`.  Do I need to add another entry to `amixer` to get the PC speaker to output to HDMI?

Answer (score 3):

`beep` application does not use ALSA or any other sound drivers at all. It uses so called `input drivers`, which support `EV_SND` events. There are couple of such drivers in Linux kernel for different beepers, like PC-Speaker or speaker build into Intel HDA card (or some more).

As far as I know, there is no driver that implements `EV_SND` events on top on any ALSA driver and since there is no other type of sound device in RapsberryPi, you just can't beep by default.

Comment: These two howto's suggest that it should work...  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disable_PC_Speaker_Beep. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disable_PC_Speaker_Beep

Comment: @shaun5: You only showed one howto, not two. And it suggest that for some cards it may be possible to change beep volume using ALSA driver. As I mentioned in my answer, some ALSA drivers (like Intel HDA) implements EV_SND events but there is no universal solution working for all the drivers (at least I don't know any).